# Will calling invalidate() from onDraw() cause a stack overflow?

Tags: android, stack-overflow, ondraw, invalidation

After much struggling, I have determined that a `SurfaceView` won't do what I want it to do, namely, be above some UI elements and below others.  I've also discovered that drawing all the UI elements on to the `SurfaceView` is actually significantly slower than the multi-layered hierarchy I was trying to replace.  Therefore, I am trying to code my own animated `View` using `onDraw()`.

The simplest method I can think of for this is roughly as follows:

1. Measure the time now
2. Perform calculations about the animation state
3. Call `invalidate()`
4. Draw the animation at `onDraw()`
5. Return to 1.

I already have a `nextFrame()` function from my `SurfaceView` which does steps 1 and 2, and the draw function is actually trivial—a single path.  I could make `nextFrame()` call `invalidate()` and I could make `onDraw()` call `nextFrame()` to signal that the drawing has completed and we are ready for the next frame.  Unfortunately, I can imagine this causing problems.

Does `invalidate()` directly call `onDraw()`?  Will I need to implement a calling thread as in `SurfaceView`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it will not cause a stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

When you call     invalidate() you can assume that the     onDraw(canvas c) is going to be called, yes.

But be careful with calling the nextFrame inside the onDraw(), be sure to control the refreshing time.

If you want to implement the     onDraw(Canvas c) method just override it and you can draw there whatever you want.

If you want to control the refreshing time based on the current time:

Inside the method 1 you said you were controlling the current time:

```
//I assume you instantiate the lasTTime in the     onCreate()

void method1() {
    while (currentTime - lastTime < N) {
        currentTime = //call the current time as you do
    }
    lastTime = currentTime;
    //call method2
}
```

Comment: I know that calling `invalidate()` causes `onDraw()` to be called, but I'm concerned that it might call it *directly* and result in a nest like `invalidate()->onDraw()->invalidate()->onDraw()` etc leading to a stack overflow (the exception not the website).  The idea is to control refreshing time based on when drawing is complete.  How would you control it?

Comment: If you Measure the time (method 1 of your description) you can compare the previous time and the current time to refresh every X miliseconds just doing a while in your first method (I'm going to edit my answer with that)

Comment: Yes, but it seems to me that presupposes a known frame rate for a device.  Isn't there a way to receive an event from a `View` that tells you the drawing cycle is complete?  I had assumed that all drawing functions in `onDraw()` occur on the UI thread, so presumably at the end of `onDraw()` the drawing cycle IS complete?

Comment: Since the     onDraw() is the end of the cycle and in the end you call the first method you can assume the drawing is done, yes. So the fps would be different but controlled.

Comment: Thank you!  I think that covers it.